# ListView not getting space to show content on smaller screens

Tags: android, android-listview, scroll

So I am developing a screen where there are some images and buttons on top and Below that is a list view which shows a list of some activity.

The design is something like this :- 
[image: design]

Now on smaller screen the ListView height becomes very small as the screen space is taken up by the above icons and images.

So how can i increase the height of the Linearlayout or ListView so that user can scroll to the see the rest of the ListView.

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
         .... Other Layouts .....

     <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listArea"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/list_padding"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/list_padding" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Edit: Tried using the top view as a header to the List but since I want an EmptyView too, this is creating a problem as it replaces the whole header + listview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I read about that issue, you should specify the Views on top as [header of the list](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView%28android.view.View%29), and the'll scroll properly.

Afaik this only works if the list is non-empty, as the empty view replaces the whole list including headers.

Comment: as I just edited (forgot the link, sorry): call `addHeaderView` on the list, with an inflated layout. So you put the Layout elements on top into a LinearLayout or something similar, as a separate XML file, and then from a `ListActivity`:

`getListView().addHeaderView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.foo, null));`

Comment: I dont think this will solve the problem as it will make the other views as fixed. That is the case now anway

Comment: The problem I am trying to fix is that the height of listview is very small in smaller screens. Can I somehow increase the height of listview so that users can scroll down to see the rest of the listview  ?

Comment: Did you try the code? As I just throwed this line into a (unrelated) android project and the header starts scrolling with the whole list (given the list is not empty, as I said above).

Comment: The issue is that a ListView is scrolling, and you cannot have concurring scrollable views on one dimension. Maybe (but I'm not sure on that) you can wrap your whole scrollable code into a `ScrollView` and give the list an fixed height or wrap_content. But I don't get what you don't like on headers.

Comment: addHeaderView Worked thanks. I already had tried the other ScrollView over Listview, didnt go well.

Comment: Ah, now I have a problem with empty view since it replaces the whole list any other suggestions ?

Comment: As I wrote in the answer, a header is not displayed while the list is empty. Depending on your project, you could insert a dummy view if the list is empty (so it technically is never empty), or you include the header view into your empty view.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [weightSum](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#weightSum) and [layout_weight](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#layout_weight) attributes to control how much of the parent's available space a child view will take up.  To use these, a parent layout, for example, your LinearLayout, gets the `android:weightSum` attribute.  Each child layout gets the `android:layout_weight` attribute, where the sum of all child weights is the weightSum of the parent.  In addition, each child should have their `layout_height` or `layout_width` set to `0dp`, whichever is going to be decided by the weight.

Here's an example based on your diagram. Let's say you want the two top views to take up 1/4 of the screen each, and the `ListView` to take up the bottom half.  Add `android:weightSum="4"` to your `LinearLayout`, `android:layout_weight="1"` to the two child layouts that you represent with `...Other Layouts...`, and `android:layout_weight="2"` to the `ListView`.  Code might look something like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:weightSum="4">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        ...some other attributes.../>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        ...some other attributes...>
        ...some children of the LinearLayout...
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listArea"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/list_padding"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/list_padding" 
        android:layout_weight="2"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks @MattDavis I didnt want to contraint the the height of the items above. I just wanted them to go up when I am scrolling  through rest of the items.