# How to show header of ListView when its empty

Tags: android-layout, android-listview, android

I am developing the following screen

[image]

The fourboxes next to each other are buttons. On clicking of the buttons I am changing the adapter of the listview.

Since the content above the listview took up lot of space I made the whole thing as an header and added it via code.

```
   myPollsList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listArea);
myPollsList.addHeaderView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.profile_listview_header, null));
```

Now I want to show some view when the list is empty. But if I do that then the header also goes away.

I am using this in a Activity and not a ListActivity. Any suggestions or workarounds for showing the header even when the list is empty ?

EDIT: Refer to my earlier question here [ListView not getting space to show content on smaller screens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17976497/listview-not-getting-space-to-show-content-on-smaller-screens) . This is where  someone suggested me to solve the problem by putting it as a header

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So this is how I solved it. I had a custom adapter which was connected to the listview. When it found that it had zero items to display. It would add a fake empty view as an item to the list.

Comment: Aghhh... All this hacks we have to do to make something that should be basic functionality work! It drives me crazy!

Answer (score 28):

I found a simple solution for this problem. If there's no elements for list and you are not adding the adapter, just add this:

```
mListView.setAdapter(null);
```

and the header will appear. It's easier than adding empty / fake item to the list.

Comment: thanks its work for me after adding these lines after addHeaderView() method

Answer (score 2):

maybe you will like this [Android addHeaderView disappears when no items in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988011/android-addheaderview-disappears-when-no-items-in-listview/5264523#5264523)

override/subclass your adapter to return false from isEmpty()

Answer (score 0):

Don't use top layouts of button as header for list view.

So to adjust UI without using list header use weights.

Give parent Linear layout weight sum as 4 and 1, 1 to top Layouts and 2 for list view.

Comment: Will that reduce the height of the top layouts ?

Comment: That is not what I want. I want the height to be the same across all devices. That is why I chose the header route so that the height of the header remains fixed. And the rest of list view can be scrolled down

Comment: as a proportion your all 3 views will be same size like 1:1:2 and also it will work great on any device just try it. cheers

Comment: Nope. This is not the effect I wanted. Thanks for the help :)