# Display Listview Header while using PullToRefreshLayout

Tags: android, listview, pull-to-refresh

I'm referring [this](http://www.tutecentral.com/android-pull-to-refresh/) tutorial for refreshing the `ListView`
and it's working great. But the problem is I'm having one `Layout` above `ListView` so when I run my application `Listview` get overrides on that `Layout`. To avoid that I did that Layout as a header to `ListView` but then a new problem arises. When a List is empty `ListView` `Header` also not get displayed. I also used isEmpty() in `Adapter` still it not showing `Header`.

Class:

```
        @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    activityView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.groups_activity_layout, null, false);

    setContentView(activityView);



    /******************************************************************************/
    ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) activityView;
    // As we're using a ListFragment we create a PullToRefreshLayout manually
    mPullToRefreshLayout = new PullToRefreshLayout(ItemscreenActivity.this);

    // We can now setup the PullToRefreshLayout
    ActionBarPullToRefresh.from(this)
    // We need to insert the PullToRefreshLayout into the Fragment's ViewGroup
    .insertLayoutInto(viewGroup)
    // Here we mark just the ListView and it's Empty View as pullable
    .theseChildrenArePullable(R.id.listView_demo_Items_gsal, android.R.id.empty).listener(this).setup(mPullToRefreshLayout);

    /******************************************************************************/

    arrayListOfAItems.clear();
    populateItemsArrayList(ItemscreenActivity.this);

    ItemsListWrtCnt++;
    // Getting the reference of Button and ListView
    listViewOfItems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView_demo_Items_gsal);

    // Get Data in Adapter to set on ListView
    ItemscreenActivityAdapter = new ItemscreenAdapter(ItemscreenActivity.this, R.layout.group_screen_adapter_layout, arrayListOfAItems);
    listViewOfItems.setTextFilterEnabled(false);
    listViewOfItems.setScrollingCacheEnabled(false);
    listViewOfItems.setCacheColorHint(Color.TRANSPARENT);

    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    ViewGroup header = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_activity_listview_header, listViewOfItems, false);
    listViewOfItems.addHeaderView(header, null, false);
    listViewOfItems.setEmptyView(header);
    listViewOfItems.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    if (arrayListOfAItems.size() > 0) {
        // Set Adapter to ListView of group if there are Items
        ItemscreenActivityAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        listViewOfItems.setAdapter(ItemscreenActivityAdapter);
        ItemsListWrtCnt--;
    } else {
        // Show Toast if no group to display
        Toast.makeText(ItemscreenActivity.this, "No Items", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.oi.demo.actionbarpulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layout_Items"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:ignore="UselessParent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView_demo_Items_gsal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/view_layout_footer_gsal"
        android:animationCache="false"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:persistentDrawingCache="scrolling"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:scrollingCache="false"
        android:smoothScrollbar="true" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view_layout_footer_gsal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="#952d4a" />

</com.oi.demo.actionbarpulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshLayout>
```

Comment: Please post your xml file code. Also show code of binding data in your listview.

Comment: @GrlsHu I added My code please check it..

Comment: @Akki try changing this `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` to `android:layout_height="match_parent"` and see if that helps (haven't tried though but that's my best guess)

Comment: @GrIsHu have you gone through my code

Comment: @Akki how about adding a fake empty view as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18127132/how-to-show-header-of-listview-when-its-empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is just set adapter out side the if condition. as:

```
if (arrayListOfAItems.size() > 0) {
    // Set Adapter to ListView of group if there are Items
    ItemscreenActivityAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    ItemsListWrtCnt--;
} else {
    // Show Toast if no group to display
    Toast.makeText(ItemscreenActivity.this, "No Items", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

listViewOfItems.setAdapter(ItemscreenActivityAdapter);
```

As to display header you need to set adapter any how.
As while your list is empty, adapter is not set so you are not able to see header.

Try it. It will work surely.